# PayPal Payment ID's

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, payment-gateway

I am using the PayPal PHP SDK for an e commerce website for handle payments. I am also updating the website, which before used php's Curl to initiate and handle communications between us and PayPal. The previous developer stored a shite load of information in the database about each transaction. It seems like that this same information is returned with each call of the API. Can I just store the Payment ID and use it if I need to gather information about that payment? How long is this ID good for? Does it expire?

Comment: The reason why people store all this information is so that there is no need to have the login details of the paypal account. Big companies will never give one of their employee's their paypal account just to resolve an issue.

Comment: What if it is storing just the Payment ID in a local database and then having a system use the ID & PayPal SDK to get the information from PayPal?

Comment: If that is possible within the API I would definatly go for that. That's the best and clean way to do this. These ID's should not expire but you should just incase just read through the API carefully to see if there is an expiry time given there.

Comment: That is my question. I read through the documentation and it makes know mention of payment I'd expiring. For the sake of time I will assume that they dont. I will keep it on my list to research this topic deeper once the project is complete and we move into the maintenence stage. Thank you for your assistance sir.